# How do I delete ubuntu entirely and then install Windows 8 from an ISO I have on an SD card?

Tags: uninstall, windows-8, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I would no longer like to have ubuntu on my laptop.  I have recently placed an ISO file for Windows 8 on to an SD card (formatted as FAT).  Can someone give me the steps necessary to ehtirely getting rid of ubuntu and then installing/booting Windows 8 from my SD card?

Answer (score 1):

Note: Do you have a Windows 8 Product key? Windows 8 now requires the product key at the start of the installation. Unlike XP/Vista/7 where you had a certain trial period after it was installed. You won't be able to proceed with the installation without the product key.

If you do then it's pretty easy to erase Ubuntu.

- Boot from the Windows 8 LiveUSB.
- Go through the standard installation steps (Regional settings, Entering Product Key etc.) until you see this screen:

  [image: Custom]
- You'll want to choose `Custom:Install Windows Only (Advanced)`. This option will allow you to erase the current (Ubuntu) partitions that are on your hard drive.
- Delete all the partitions that are in the list. (Note: This will entirely get rid of Ubuntu as you requested. This includes any pictures, music, documents etc that you had in Ubuntu.)
- If you deleted them correctly you will see one partition labelled as `Unallocated Space`

[image: Unallocated Space]

- Select this partition and click `Next` to continue with the standard Windows 8 install.

If you need any help with the standard Windows 8 install see [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-1.htm) for a detailed guide.